# Make proxy of all requests for arbitrary AWS S3 buckets URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a some data in amazon s3's bucket Now I am getting images from bucket to my site But its URL looks like http://mybucket-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/logo_1_2.png in inspect element.

I want to hide this URL from inspect element and Its look like that image is coming from my server not from amazon.

Is it possible and how ?

I was trying mod_proxy but I don't know how to use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about mod_proxy, I'm assuming you are using Apache httpd to do this?  You should be able to do this with mod_proxy if you already have apache setup.  Assume that the mod_proxy module is already loaded (usually is by default), you should be able to just add something like the following to your httpd.conf

```
<LocationMatch /images/(.*)>
  ProxyPassMatch http://mybucket-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/$1
</LocationMatch>
```

This will forward a call from www.yourdomain.com/images/logo_1_2.png to http://mybucket-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/logo_1_2.png...

Hope that helps.  Another option if you have access to your DNS is to add a CNAME record that will just forward all requests from one subdomain to your s3 bucket domain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think you misunderstood the question, I said I was getting an image from amazon on my site. when I see its URL it is something like this http://mybucket-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/logo_1_2.png but I want to hide it from end user, I want end user to get that image is coming from my server not from amazon server but that fact that image is coming from amazon server, In simple word I wanna to make end user fool that image is coming from my server.

Comment: What technology are you working in?  Where is your website hosted?  Do you control the servers that your website is hosted on?  If so, the above solution would do the trick (assuming you are using apache).   Are you trying to do this all client side or something?

Comment: Yes, I am using apache and I am working on my machine (local), I tried above solution but it is not working.